# Print stylish text on image in php

Tags: php, image, text

Is it possible to print html div tag with style on image in PHP?. if not, then what is the alternative way?

Comment: mind to share what is on your **mega mind** ? Or even an URL to illustrate your expected output ?

Comment: but i need to produce as jpg image. (sorry i forgot to mention in my question)

Comment: You're looking for a function to save styled html as an image? That would be a challenge for a coder with available time. >> function html2png($html,$css) 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the image as the background graphic of any div using CSS. Then the text within that div will appear on top of the image.

```
(CSS)
.mydiv {
    background:url(/path/to/image.gif);
    width:100px;  /* set to width of the image */
    height:100px;  /* set to height of the image */
}

(HTML)
<div class='mydiv'>Some text here</div>
```

Comment: but i need to produce as jpg image. (sorry i forgot to mention in my question)

Comment: @Kumar V - you can use any type of image (gif, png or jpg) in this way.

Comment: not like that. final output should be image. I used GD function to produce image. but it;s not allowing me to add style in text.

Comment: ehmm... now I really don't know what you are trying to ask. Your question really didn't sound like it was asking about GD. It sounded like a CSS/HTML question. Perhaps you need to re-formulate the question.

Answer (score 1):

Some hosts have ImageMagick for PHP. To add text to your image, take a look at the syntax of the commands [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-annotateimage.php). The example given on that page should help some - it's pretty easy to get text on an image.

The benefits of using ImageMagick over a fixed image is that you can vary the content of the text, which is what you might want (you didn't mention needing a static text; for this, I'd use an image with a transparent background). For more comprehensive font commands, take a look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/).

To put a transparent image on top of your base image, take a look at [this very nicely designed site](http://www.benholmen.com/blog/2008/12/adding-png-watermarks-to-jpegs-with-php/).

I'll also give the code presented on that site here:

```
$photo = imagecreatefromjpeg("original.jpg");
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng("watermark.png");

// This is the key. Without ImageAlphaBlending on, the PNG won't render correctly.
imagealphablending($photo, true);

// Copy the watermark onto the master, $offset px from the bottom right corner.
$offset = 10;

imagecopy($photo, $watermark, imagesx($photo) - imagesx($watermark) - $offset, imagesy($photo) - imagesy($watermark) - $offset, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

// Output to the browser
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($photo);
```

To output the image to a file, please Google that and replace the last two lines of the example given above.

For ImageMagick stuff, take a look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php)

I hope this helps :-)

James

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to print text on images using html/css on server side, because php can't parse html, so you'd better find another solution like [php GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).